Cookie-based request credentials in Blazor
I'm using blazor .net with interactive auto and individual accounts. When I send a request from the client to my server/api, I can't insert the cookies in the request header.
Following the documentation I tried this approach.
My client:
public class CookieHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", ["XMLHttpRequest"]);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

builder.Services.AddTransient<CookieHandler>()
    .AddScoped(sp => sp
        .GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
        .CreateClient("API"))
    .AddHttpClient("API", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CookieHandler>();

My server:
builder.Services.AddScoped(http => new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7138")
});

In the following image, my httpClient doesn't have cookies

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Does the document you mentioned following to is this section? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cookie-based-request-credentials   And then when you want to use httpclient to send http request? In the client project or the server project?

Yes, is that section. I'm trying to apply it on the client side.

Please bear in mind that the HttpRequestMessage contains the cookies, not the HttpClient. HttpClient's underlying HttpMessageHandler which is normally a HttpClientHandler contains only a CookieContainer

What do you suggest, then, is not using httpclient? What am I supposed to do?

I had a test in my side and it worked well finally.
I created a new .Net 8 blazor web app which render mode is InternativeAuto. I choose the Identity Type to be Individual Accounts so that I will integrate Asp.net Core default Identity Scheme in this app which is a like of cookie-based authentication.

Then let's see the section in the document:

The guidance in this section applies to client-side scenarios that
rely upon an authentication cookie.
For cookie-based authentication, which is considered more secure than
bearer token authentication, cookie credentials can be sent with each
web API request by calling AddHttpMessageHandler with a
DelegatingHandler on a preconfigured HttpClient.

Therefore, in the Client project we need to force the client to send the HTTP request. Firstly, let's create the CookieHandler just like the document demonstrates to us and inject it in Program.cs of the Client project.
builder.Services.AddTransient<CookieHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI2", client =>
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7203")).AddHttpMessageHandler<CookieHandler>();

Then in the default Counter.razor component, we need to comment the default @rendermode InteractiveAuto and use @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly, otherwise, it will use server side request.
@page "/counter"
@* @rendermode InteractiveAuto *@
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="call">call API </button>

@code {
    public async Task call()
    { 
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("WebAPI2");
        var res = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:7203/api/Test");
    }
}

Since the request will include cookie credential, and we want to call an external API, we need to specify the API to allow credential in its CORS policy otherwise we will get CORS error.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "mypolicy",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7020").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
                      });
});

Here's my test result. Just like you see the cookie is included in the request header.


I tried that and, for me, the request still doesn't set cookies. Maybe it works for you because you only call the API when you press the button and I call the API in OnInitializedAsync.

@FranciscoFernandes Hi, I test in my side putting the call() method in OnInitializedAsync and it worked as well. May I know weather there's such kind of cookie existed in the browser? I test in my side which calling the API before login, then I could see in Application blade of browser and there's no cookie for .AspNetCOre.Identity, so that the API request doesn't have it in request header.

in my case i always have the forgery cookie the and identity cookie because i only allow access to authenticated users, but they dont appear in request

Could you please provide a minimal sample for reproducing the issue? I already shared a  working sample but it looks not helpful to you. I trust there must be some differences between your project and my sample.

@FranciscoFernandes   In my case, it's blazor web app render mode auto, but in my component in the client project, I define the render mode to be web assembly to match the official document description. Could you please let me know weather you are trying to call API from the client or the server?

i'm using render mode auto, so i have made the calls in both, but i have create a service on the server and another on the client to adapt the request. If it's the interactive server that made the call to the api, i go to the httpcontext get the cookies and insert them into the request, if it's insteractive wasm the app already send the cookies. I don't think it's the ideal approach, but I have no other solution for the moment.

I might get your point now. Per my understanding, blazor auto rendered mode is deisnged for developers to enjoy the advantanges from server-render-mode and client-render-mode. And what you did seems that you thin your app will randomly send http request from the client or the server. I don't think it would occur as per my test, when I use auto render mode, it will always send http request from the server. Therefore, if you prefer to send from server, then go to the httpcontext pls, of you prefer the client, then follow the offical link you shared.

I don't think it's random, when I have the interactive auto, the application goes to the server if it's the first time, because it's using the interactive server, if I reload the page then it already goes through the client because it's using the interactive Wasm. that's why I need both calls to have cookies (servwer and client).
Otherwise, the cookies will only work on one of the approaches and not on the interactive auto.

I can understand your concerns now. You insist on using interative auto mode in your componenty, then the first time you wanna call api, it will go through the server side, but the next time the wasm is already loaded, it will always call api from the client side. Then just like what you said you have to both have the call-api-logic in server and client.
